# Php : variable not transmitted into a foreach

Tags: php, string, foreach

Probably a stupid question here, I apologize...

I have a SQL request into a foreach, like below.
The "auth" string is correctly defined, a "echo $auth" returns what I want. But the sql request returns nothing.

```
// $auth=something;
$val=array(value1,value2,value3);

   foreach ($val as $j)
      {
         $req = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,"select val from user where auth='$auth'"));
         $$j=$req[val];
      }
```

My goal is to select the sql fieds contained in the $val array (it perfectly works in others parts of my project). Thanks in advance.

I also tried this, still does not return anything :

```
    $val = array('mail','preferences','info','langue'); // This must be an array  
    $fields = explode(",", $val);

   $req = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,"select $fields from user where auth='$auth'"));

   $mail = $req[0]; $preferences = $req[1]; $info = $req[2]; $info = $req[3];
```

Comment: What you really want to do..

Comment: I edited the question to give you more infos. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible typo : `$$j=$req[val];` ?

Comment: Running the query three times doesn't seem senseful. You're just assigning the very same result value to three variables. Or is `$j` used anywhere? Is this the complete code? What's the exact `var_dump()` value of `$auth` then? Also turn on error_reporting. You should at least get an undefined constant notice.

Comment: DNReNTi : this part works perfecly, it returns immediatly the variable as $field. More helpful to me. mario : $j not used anywhere else, this is quite the complete code (with mysqli instanced before, of course) and a var_dump of $auth returns a string, so this is correct... I'm going to turn on error_reporting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to select the sql fieds contained in the `$val` array

So the `$val` contains the fields you want to use on your query. You can use an `explode()` to retrieve all the fields without a `foreach`:

```
$fields = explode(",", $val);

$req = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,"select $fields from user where auth='$auth'"));
```

And the you can get the value:

```
$value1 = $req[$val[0]]; // First field
```

Comment: I think not unfortunately (you can see the added code into my question)

Comment: If you write `$fields = explode(",", mail,preferences,info,langue);` in your code, it's an error. You have to do: `$val = array('mail','preferences','info','langue'); $fields = explode(",", $val);` EXACTLY as i wrote.

Comment: Yes, indeed I tried with all quotes configurations possibles... still does not work, I'm sorry...

Comment: Did you try to print the sql query and run it directly on mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's resume all that. so we have two methods. First :

```
   $val=array(mail,preferences,info,langue);

   foreach ($val as $j)
      {
         $auth = $_SESSION['auth'];
         echo $auth; //this works
         $req = "select val from user where auth='$auth'";//this works only in phpMyadmin
         $req = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,$req));
         $$j=$req[val];
      }
   echo $mail; //gives nothing of course...
```

And here's the second one :

```
val = array('mail','preferences','info','langue');
$fields = explode(",", $val);
$req = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,"select $fields from user where auth='$auth'"));
$mail = $req[$val[0]]; $preferences = $req[$val[1]]; $info = $req[$val[2]]; $info = $req[$val[3]];
```

Still nothing works. No php problem detected, my Mysqli instances work correctly... PLEASE do notice we are in debug mode, so my first code is not optimized of course...

Comment: I added an answer with a short explanation. Please have a look at it and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work either... anyways, have you any idea about the first code given above ? Still does not work... this does not make sense...

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to select the columns in the array `$val`, correct? Then you want to assign the returned row into its respective variables, correct?

Comment: Yes. But anyways, I solved the problem by selecting all the row... not efficient, but we can consider the problem solved... thank you anyways...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of `explode` which splits a string on a delimiter and create an array. You already have an array, but you want to make it a string. To do this you can use `implode`:

```
$columns = array("mail", "preferences", "info", "language");
$sql = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM user WHERE auth='%s'", implode(",", $columns), $auth);

$query = mysqli_query($sql); //..fetch possible errors
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); //..make sure a row was returned
list($mail, $preferences, $info, $language) = $row;
echo $mail;
```